# How is the Cofinite Topology on an infinite set even possible?

Tags: general-topology

To be a topology we need the empty set to be open but- X is not finite so the empty set can't be in it and if X was finite every subset of X would be in the topology...

Comment: There is a special exception for the empty set.

Comment: What the. .. I've been downvoted for posting a duplicate- there are many ways to phrase a question- I tried to search question  before posted- couldn't find

Comment: Nobody, including you, knows why your question was downvoted, except the people who voted it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the cofinite topology is that the open sets are the cofinite sets *and* the empty set.